# WebGL context is redrawn completely for no apparent reason

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, webgl

I'm experimenting with WebGL and it seems to me that I've missing something very basic but still can not find in docs and examples what exactly. So imagine I want to draw a rectangle, id do something like this:

```
let points = rectangle(20, 20, 100, 100)
gl.bufferData(WebGLRenderingContext.ARRAY_BUFFER, convertFloat32(points), WebGLRenderingContext.STATIC_DRAW)
gl.drawArrays(WebGLRenderingContext.LINE_STRIP, 0, points.length)
```

This works. I see a rectangle drawn an cannot be more happier. Same holds true about drawing as many rectangles as I want to.

However, whenever I'm trying to add something like this:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    let points = rectangle(120, 120, 100, 100)
    gl.bufferData(WebGLRenderingContext.ARRAY_BUFFER, convertFloat32(points), WebGLRenderingContext.STATIC_DRAW)
    gl.drawArrays(WebGLRenderingContext.LINE_STRIP, 0, points.length)
}, 1000);
```

or, say to draw rectangles in some DOM event handler, all that previously has been drawn is erased and I have no clue why.

My question would be - what do I missing exactly?

UPD: I've forked some existing example and modified it to have (sort of) minimal example of what I'm talking about - https://codepen.io/shabunc/pen/YRgzJq?editors=1010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a a second argument - some optional parameters - for the `getCcontext()` method.

In Your example, try adding following lines of code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("c");

var NO_ANTIALIAS = false, 
    CLEAR_DRAWING_BUFFER = false,
    attributes = {antialias: !NO_ANTIALIAS, preserveDrawingBuffer: !CLEAR_DRAWING_BUFFER};

var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl", attributes);
```

Explanation:

- **antialias**: this is just a hint for the browser - when available, try
  to smooth drawing borders
- **preserveDrawingBuffer**: You need to take care of clearing the drawing 
  buffer by Your self

Here is the reference: [WebGL Specification - Context creation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#2.1)