# WebGL: When I try to draw multiple objects with separate draw calls, WebGL returns only the last result

Tags: loops, buffer, webgl

Trying to draw multiple objects in WebGL.
Each object has its own data. I use loop to draw each object at a time. And WebGL shows only the last object. When I try to draw them separately from each other (click one time - the first one is drawn, click second time - then the next object drawn over the first one) everything is fine. Is it possible to use multiple draw-calls for separate object in a loop and to get one combined image?
PS: I dont use 'clear' functions inside the loop.

Here is some code.

Object structure:

```
let someObject = {
    // Program to execute
    program: program,
    // Vertex buffer
    buffer: positionBuffer,
    // Vertex attribute location
    attribLocation: positionAttributeLocation,
    // Data per primitive
    count: positions.length / 2, // 2 values per vertex: X, Y
    // Uniforms
    // [{type, vareableLocation, valueToPass}, ...]
    uniforms: updateObjectUniforms(program)
};
```

Drawing loop-call

```
for (let i = 0; i < objectsToDraw.length; i++) {
    drawObject(objectsToDraw[i]);
}
```

I use gl.darwArrays function

```
function drawObject(object) {
    var programInfo = object.programInfo;
    var bufferInfo = object.bufferInfo;

    gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);

    // Setup all the needed attributes
    // Bind buffers
    ...

    // Upload uniforms
    ...

    // Draw
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, bufferInfo.numElements);
});
```

Comment: I tried to use var gl = someCanvas.getContext("webgl", { preserveDrawingBuffer: true }); But it didn't help.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the pseudo code you posted. The issue is somewhere else. Post more code. Ideally the **smallest** code that reproduces the issue. Maybe use a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: `Is it possible to use multiple draw-calls for separate object in a loop and to get one combined image?` Of course it is possible. I can only assume you messed up in your `drawObject()`. My bet is that you mixed up buffers in some way.

Comment: what about `gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);`?And where did you call `gl.clear`?

Comment: just guessing, maybe the same problem as here: [WebGL context is redrawn completely for no apparent reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53659730/4845566)

Comment: Thank you all.  @zoran404 is right. Trying to simplify the code to add to the snippet, as @gman  suggested, i got the correct result. Now I'll try to figure out where the error accrued. There is no need to use `code` preserveDrawingBuffer: true `code`.